# Own authentication activity in locked mode of Android smartphone

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, lg

I have a problem with the fingerprint authentication in Android.
When the smartphone (using a LG G5) is locked and I start over a service an own activity for authentication in the foreground over the flags **FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED** and **FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON** the fingerprint sensor is not reacting.

Is there any possibility to use the authentication in this way? Or can I receive (e.g. over a broadcast) the fingerprint event of the system?